# Network communication from EC2 instance to/from internet via HTTP, TCP and UDP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, aws-elb

We have one app deployed on an EC2 instance that can communicate inbound/outbound using HTTP, TCP, and UDP protocols.

One option could be to have an ALB for HTTP traffic and an NLB for TCP, UDP traffic.

The challenge is that the application allows the configuration of a single target FQDN so we can't target both the NLB and ALB based on the protocol.

As we don't want to go to classic ELB I'm wondering how others implemented a solution for similar challenges. Would AWS Global Accelerator help in such a case?

Comment: Why won't an NLB work for your HTTP traffic? Are there specific features of the ALB you need for the HTTP traffic?

Comment: It does look like AWS Global Accelerator would solve this problem.

Comment: Thank you @MarkB, indeed behind the ALB there are other instances receiving/sending HTTP traffic and are already attached to the ALB.